# Obtener el top 5 por cada grupo - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, ordenamiento, group-by

Requiero obtener el top 5 del total de VtaBS(ventas) por gerencia.

Tabla inicial

[image: Tabla inicial]

Tabla resultante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Avancé:

```
select top 5 vtaBS as vtaBS201606 , gerencia
from Tickets
order by VtaBS desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, la pregunta no esta muy clara, ¿puedes agregar mas información de lo que esperas obtener?

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro si entiendo correctamente, porque por algún motivo muestras el código de la suma agrupada por gerencia, y luego dices que quieres el top 5 por gerencia (sin suma).

Asumiendo que en efecto lo que necesitas son los 5 valores más altos de VtaBS de cada gerencia, el siguiente código te serviría:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Gerencia ORDER BY VtaBS DESC) RN
    FROM Tickets
)
SELECT VtaBS vtaBS201606, Gerencia
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 5
;
```

Comment: Gracias Lamak, me sirvió. Podrías explicarme la tercera línea, desde el SELECT.